# Icon bar not syncing with the slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

So on this page there's a slider with several full screen slides an icon bar on the side that lets you navigate between the slides.
https://www.maloufsleep.com/quality-pillows/

now the problem is that if you click on one of the icons it jumps to the correct slide but the wrong icon lights up. for example if you click on z-gel, latex light up. and also if you scroll up the icons do the same thing. I didn't make this page but I was asked to fix it. I worked on it for a while but I have no idea what the problem is. Can anyone help me figure out what is causing this problem?

Thanks

```js
// show the active quality page icon
   $('#icons .icon img').removeClass('active');
   if(slide == 0 || slide == 1) { quality = 1; }
   if(slide > 1) { quality = slide; }
   $('.quality-' + quality).addClass('active');
```

```html
<div id="icons" class="outline">
 <div class="icon outline">
  <a href="#top" class="scroll"><img src="/assets/images/Pillow_MemoryFoam.png" class="quality-1" /></a>
 </div>
 <div class="icon outline">
  <a href="#slide-2" class="scroll"><img src="/assets/images/Pillow_Latex.png" class="quality-2" /></a>
 </div>
 <div class="icon outline">
  <a href="#slide-3" class="scroll"><img src="/assets/images/quality/Pillows/Pillow_ZGel.png" class="quality-3" /></a>
 </div>
 <div class="icon outline">
  <a href="#slide-4" class="scroll"><img src="/assets/images/quality/Pillows/Pillow_GelledMicrofiber.png" class="quality-4" /></a>
 </div>
 <div class="icon outline">
  <a href="#slide-5" class="scroll"><img src="/assets/images/Pillow_2sidedComf.png" class="quality-5" /></a>
 </div>
 <div class="icon outline">
  <a href="#slide-6" class="scroll"><img src="/assets/images/Pillow_Zoned.png" class="quality-6" /></a>
 </div>
 <div class="icon outline">
  <a href="#slide-7" class="scroll"><img src="/assets/images/quality/Pillows/Pillow_GelDough.png" class="quality-7" /></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this jQuery `$('body').find('.icon.outline').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active')` inside slide change function.

Comment: thanks you, but unfortunately it didn't fix the issue